# creating a string based on array's indexes

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to create a function with will do the following:
There is an array built in the form of

```
$array = [
    0 => 1,
    1 => 2,
    2 => 4,
];
```

i want to create a string in the length of 5, in which the values of the current array in the correct order, like: 12040.

or

```
$array = [
    0 => 3,
    1 => 5,
];
```

will become: 00305

essentially, replacing the places that don't exist in the array with 0 in the string.

thank you!

Comment: How does: `[1,2,4]` become `1204` and `[3,5]` -> `00305` ? I don't see the pattern behind it

Comment: confusing....what do you want to achieve?

Comment: @Rizier123 it looks like the `0`s are where the value does not exist - ie. `[1,2,4]` is missing the `3,5`, so they want to do `[1,2,0,4,0]` or `12040`, and `[0,0,3,0,5]`/`00305` since the `1,2,4` are not set

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not 100% certain I understood what you meant, but I think you are looking for this:

```
$finalString = "";
for ($i = 0, $j = count($myArray); $i < $j; $i++)
{
    if (isset($myArray[$i]))
    {
        $finalString .= $myArray[$i];
    }
    else
    {
        $finalString .= "0";
    }
}
```

**EDIT:** I realised you are probably looking for this:

```
$myArray = [3, 5];
$finalString = "";
for ($i = 1; $i <= 5; $i++)
{
    if (in_array($i, $myArray))
    {
        $finalString .= $i;
    }
    else
    {
        $finalString .= "0";
    }
}
```

After this `$finalString` contains `00305`. If you want to continue this further than just 5 spaces, just change the 5 in the loop.

Comment: Personally I'd prefer arkascha's solution in production code. I wrote it like this to make it clear and understandable for the OP. **One important difference:** arkascha's solution never will create a string longer than the highest value in the array. So you'd **never** get trailing 0's. So with `[2]` as input you'd get `02` back, not `02000`.

Answer (score 3):

Something like this should be what you are looking for:

```
<?php
$input = [1,2,5,6,8];
$string = '';
for ($i=1; $i<=max($input); $i++) {
    $string .= in_array($i, $input) ? $i : '0';
}
var_dump($string);
```

The output is:

```
string(8) "12005608"
```

Comment: +1. However, this assumes that the highest number in the array is the last number of the string. Whereas, in the first example given in the question, the string also "checks" for the number 5, which is not present in the array.